# Scheduling teamcity build with different custom parameters at different time

Tags: teamcity

I am new to teamcity. I have created a build which should be run with different parameters. Is there a way to schedule builds to run with different parameters ?
That means, I should set x value for a parameter for a build scheduled at 9 AM and y value for a parameter for a build scheduled at 10 AM. I looked into schedule trigger,but I couldn't find a way to give custom parameters for each triggers

Answer (score 1):

Convert your build configuration into template. Then, create another build based on this template. Add different parameters into those build configuration and run them on different hours with build scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to be more conservative with the number of build configurations used then create two different shell scripts that if ran by the correct trigger would produce your desired results (ex: setting env variables). Then in the Schedule Triggers add a trigger rule that excludes the shell file you do not want. In the build step if one script exists run it else run the other. But you should prefer the answer given by @Peska in most cases.

very basic example:

```
    touch test{1,2}.sh #will create two files named ./test1.sh and ./test2.sh

    #Trigger rule excludes one

    ./test?.sh #will run all files matching that pattern
```